# Python decision tree and random forest results

Tags: python, random-forest, decision-tree

I have a data set of 11800 lines and around 50 rows.
I have performed both Decision tree regression and Random forest regression.
Both have weights applied to them, to take care of right censored information issues.

My code for the Decision tree (a look at the variables):

```
#Importance des paramètres 
reg= DecisionTreeRegressor()
reg.fit(X_train,y_train)
predictors=list(X_train)
reg.feature_importances_
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
feat_imp = pd.Series(reg.feature_importances_, predictors).sort_values(ascending=False)
feat_imp.plot(kind='bar', title='Importance des variables')
plt.show()
```

**Importance of the variables**

[image: Importance of the variables]

Then I use gridsearch to get my best parameters:

```
grid=GridSearchCV(reg,param_grid=param_dict,cv=10,verbose=1,n_jobs=-1)
grid.fit(X_train,y_train,sample_weight=Vect_Poids)
```

And apply it to my datas:

```
reg= DecisionTreeRegressor(criterion='friedman_mse', max_depth=17, min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=16, splitter='random',random_state = random.seed(1234))
reg.fit(X_train,y_train,sample_weight=Vect_Poids)
```

For my results:

```
print('R2 score for REF',r2_score(y_test,y_pred))
print('Root Mean Square error REF',sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test,y_pred)))
```

The prediction,s aren't great, but not that bad:

**Differences between predict and test**

[image: Differences between predict and test]

I get an R² around 0.58.

But when I do the same thing with a random forest regressor, I get an R² of 0.30.

**Prediction is far from test**

[image: Prediction is far from test]

Is there an obvious reason for that?
I thought Random forest was always better than a decision tree?
How could I get better R² results than with my decision tree regressor?

Comment: I've tried and loop my decision tree and random forest, to get 100 R². 
They are extremely different at each time. The means of all the R² is aroung 0.25
Does it mean my datas are not good enough for these methods? is it overfitting?

Comment: How have you created your RF?